# Reliable and persistent installation of the Nvidia driver on Centos 5

Tags: centos, xorg, package-management, nvidia

We have a bunch of computers controlling equipment that run on Centos 5. We also need to use the proprietary Nvidia driver, the default nv driver doesn't work correctly with some software we need.

Just installing the proprietary driver with the installation script from the Nvidia homepage works fine, until a kernel update takes place. Then I have some confused users calling me because X doesn't start anymore.

The solution to that issue was to install the Nvidia driver with dkms enabled. This solved the issue and the driver is properly updated along with the kernel as far as I can tell so far. But it caused a new issue, starting Firefox with the dkms-enabled driver crashes the X server.

Both versions are far from ideal, having to babysit each kernel update and install the driver again is seriously annoying. Firefox crashing X is even worse.

What is the current, recommended way to install the proprietary NVidia driver on the latest Centos 5 in a way that survives kernel updates?

Answer (score 1):

The `nvidia` kernel module must be rebuilt with each kernel update because the `nvidia.ko`module is built and placed in the modules directory for each kernel.  This occurs for a few reasons (off the top of my head):

1. The module is binary.
2. Each build requires access to the new kernel headers.
3. The dkms mode switching interferes with the binary module.

The reason Firefox crashes X is because Firefox attempts to start/use 3D acceleration.  As such, you need to make sure the OpenGL driver is set to Nvidia, and not the default XOrg OpenGL driver.  If that is already set, the cards you use don't support 3D and/or you need to:

1. Disable 3D Acceleration in all apps, or:
2. Remove the DKMS.

The DKMS isn't compatible with the binary blob.